# Я хочу чтобы телеграм бот отвечал на моё второе сообщения

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Такой код я имею:

```
@bot.message_handler()
def get_message(message):
    if message.text == 'Да или нет':
        if message.text:
            mylist = ["Нет", "Да"]
            bot.reply_to(message, random.choice(mylist))
```

Вот что я хочу:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: if message.text == '"Вопрос"' вот так хотите?

Comment: Да, именно так я и хочу!